# Magento 2: How to validate duplicate data on customer CSV import

Tags: magento2.2, customer, import, customer-attribute, customer-csv

I would like to validate duplicate data for one attribute for customer import file.

I am trying to check it in `Magento\CustomerImportExport\Model\Import\Customer` class with `validateRow` function but in this i will get only one row data

How can i get whole row data and compare current row with whole csv data.
eg.

[image]

Comment: What do you want to achive? You want not to import customers if at least one customer with needed attribute was already imported before?

Comment: No i want to validate customer data before import like i have one attribute and data should not be duplicate for each row.

Comment: I can't understand what data should not be duplicated. Maybe provide an example with two rows

Comment: I have added image in this customattribute data is duplicate i wan to validate that before proceed.So when cutomattribute is duplicate then it should show error before import on validate data

Comment: @magentostacker have you found any solution for this?